# Using session context manager and stream=True at the same time

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I was wondering if this code is safe:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.get("http://google.com", stream=True)
content = response.content
```

For example simple like this, this does not fail (note I don't write "it works" :p), since the pool does not close instantly the connection anyway (that's a point of a session/pool right?).

Using `stream=True`, the response object is supposed to have its `raw` attribute that contains the connection, but I'm unsure if the connection is owned by the session or not, and then if at some point if I don't read the content right now but later, it might have been closed.

My current 2 cents is that it's unsafe, but I'm not 100% sure.

Thanks!

**[Edit after reading requests code]**

After reading the requests code in more details, it seems that it's what `requests.get` is doing itself:

https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py

```
def request(method, url, **kwargs):
    with sessions.Session() as session:
        return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
```

Being that kwargs might contain `stream`.

So I guess the answer is "it's safe".

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/ see "Body Content Workflow"

Comment: I read this link before asking the question, this does not mention the behavior with Session object AND stream at the time.

Comment: Oh, my bad! I looked back and forth between them and missed that like a dummy. This is a good question. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I got my answer by digging in `requests` and `urllib3`

The `Response` object own the connection until the `close()` method is explicitly called:

https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/24092b11d74af0a766d9cc616622f38adb0044b9/requests/models.py#L937-L948

```
def close(self):
    """Releases the connection back to the pool. Once this method has been
    called the underlying ``raw`` object must not be accessed again.
    *Note: Should not normally need to be called explicitly.*
    """
    if not self._content_consumed:
        self.raw.close()

    release_conn = getattr(self.raw, 'release_conn', None)
    if release_conn is not None:
        release_conn()
```

`release_conn()` is a `urllib3` method, this releases the connection and put it back in the pool

```
def release_conn(self):
    if not self._pool or not self._connection:
        return

    self._pool._put_conn(self._connection)
    self._connection = None
```

If the `Session` was destroyed (like using the `with`), the pool was destroyed, the connection cannot be put back and it's just closed.

TL;DR; This is safe.

Note that this also means that in `stream` mode, the connection is not available for the pool until the response is closed explicitly or the content read entirely.

Comment: with [requests 2.18.0](https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/4137) we are able to use `with requests.get(url,stream= True) as r:` this avoids the problem of manually closing the connection by calling `r.close` we can also use this alongside with sessions by wrapping `with s.get(url,stream=True) as r:` inside of `with requests.Session() as s:`